# jQuery.remove() not removing element

Tags: jquery

I am creating a widget (a parent div with child divs and anchors) dynamically on the page and I want to remove the widget from the page based on user's Click action on a div (shown as a close button) which is a child div of the widget.

The event handler for the "close button" is bound to this element using the following:

```
$("#elemID").on('click', callbackFunc)
```

When the callbackFunc is called, it in turn calls another function to remove the widget (the parent of the close button) from the page using:

```
$("#elemIdOFWidget").remove();
```

but the following error is generated:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'origType' of undefined(…)

The same error is generated if I use the debugger to try to remove the widget directly.
Interestingly enough, detach does work on the same element with no errors:

```
$("#elemIdOFWidget").detach();
```

My questions:

- What does the error generated mean?
- Why remove() does not work on the element but detach() does?
- Also, it seems if I attach event handler to the "close button" using plain javacript, such as:

  closeButtonElem.addEventHandler('click', callbackFunc)

then, the remove() works fine:

```
$("#elemIdOFWidget").remove();
```

but why the difference?

Thank you in advance.

Also here is an image of me using the debugger to test this on another element. on the first attempt of removing the element using

```
$(".siteTitleClass").remove()
```

.remove() works fine but after I reload the page and as soon as I use jQuery to bind event handler to the same element, afterwords the .remove() method generates an error. There must be something that binding the event handler to the element does which causes failure in the .remove() method. Any thoughts?

[removing element using Chrome debugger after binding event handler using jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfVQe.jpg)

Comment: Is the difference between `#elemID` and `#elemIdOFWidget` a typo?

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle?

Comment: Not enough known about where the error comes from. Also not enough code here for anyone to reproduce this

Comment: Thanks for the responses. "#elemID" refers to the "close button" which the event handler is attached to. "#elemIdOFWidget" refers to the parent div which contains the close button. So close button catches the event but then the event handler should remove the parent div of that button and all of its children from the page.

Answer (score 0):

.detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

.remove() removes everything, probably not what you want with dynamic components.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of that but why .remove() generates an error as mentioned and .detach() does not?

Comment: since .remove() removes all of the data associated with the element, you might be performing some operation on data that no longer exists. That is just my guess.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That could be but what kind of possible "data" are you referring to which can be set on an element to cause this? Are you talking about "data-" attribute?